# Previous url in laravel on email click

Tags: php, laravel

I am using this code on `Login controller`:

```
session(['redirectlink' => url()->previous()]);
return redirect(session('redirectlink'));
```

This code is working well but, on email anchor tag click after login it is redirecting me to same email inbox.

Comment: Where do you want it to be redirected?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your post doesn't currently seem to be asking a question. What exactly is the intended behaviour for your application when a user visits the site via an link in an email?

Answer (score 0):

`url()->previous()` defaults to using the value of the `referer` header to know what the previous url is.

[Click here for the source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L153).

When you click a link in a web browser, the browser will send the site you're going **to** a referer header containing the url of the site you're coming **from**.

For example, let's say I'm reading my email at `https://gmail.com/...`, and in an email I click a link to your website. My browser sends your website a `referer` header with the value of `https://gmail.com/...`. That means the value of `url()->previous()` will equal `https://gmail.com/...`.

Try something like this:

```php
$prev = url()->previous();
// if the site's url is the very first part of the previous url
if(strpos($prev, config('app.url') === 0){
  // do something with the url
} else {
  // the previous link is from somewhere else, so do something 
  // different instead
}
```

Comment: When i am using this one it is giving me a error                                                                                                                                    
"url()->getPreviousUrlFromSession()" that getPreviousUrlFromSession() not exist on Urlgenerator.php but i have checked that it is on that page.

Comment: @user10803205 I removed references to that in my example. You're ok to just use `url()->previous()` with the code above. Out of curiosity, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @user10803205 I just looked at the source code again, I didn't notice the first time `getPreviousUrlFromSession` is marked as protected. That's my bad. We can't use that method, but the above code should point you towards a solution.